# How can I change these graphs to line graphs or other better to understand type?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change the following graphs to line graphs or other better understandable type.

```
import os
import itertools
import pvlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.style
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pvlib import clearsky, atmosphere, solarposition
from pvlib.location import Location
from pvlib.iotools import read_tmy3

tus = Location(28.6, 77.2, 'Asia/Kolkata', 216, 'Delhi')
times = pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-12-31', freq='1min', tz=tus.tz)
cs = tus.get_clearsky(times)
cs.plot();
plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('Irradiance $W/m^2$');
plt.title('Ineichen, climatological turbidity');
```

Irradiance data:

[image: Irradiance data]

Also, how can I place the legend to suitable position.

Comment: what kind of data structure does `tus.get_clearsky` return? is it a dataframe? if so, you should look at the docs for `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

Comment: @PaulH yes it's a data frame. What exactly to look in the doc?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Pandas plots by default line graphs. The graph that you are showing is actually a line graph, there are just so many lines that it looks like a solid plot!

To see this, try and only plot the first 1440 rows (one day), i.e.:

```
cs.iloc[:1440].plot()
```

If you want to visualize annual data you need to do some kind of aggregation for it to make sense. For example, resample to average daily irradiance and plot this:

```
cs.resample('1d').mean().plot()
```

To change the legend use the plt.legend command:

```
cs.resample('1d').mean().plot()
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)
Yes, you are right about the type of graph. I also tried to resample the irradiance data but after resampling, all components of radiation decreased. The y-axis of the graph in the question goes up to 1000W/m2 but now it's only 350W/m2.

Comment: It makes sense that it is reduced, as you are averaging over the entire day (including nighttime). So if your maximum irradiance over the day if 1000 W/m2, then a daily average irradiance of 350 W/m2 seems reasonable.